# Connect two Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to make a auctions website for a project and I can't get to connect 2 models, I have in my models.py file, a model for the auction listings (`Alisting`) and a model for the bids that are made (`Bid`).

-The `Alisting` model has 4 fields: `title` CharField for the title of the auction, `sta_bid` for a starting bid, `las_bid` ForeignKey to `Bid` model, and `user` ForeignKey to `User` model.

-The Bid model has 3 fields: `user` ForeignKey to `User` for the user that makes the bid, `listing` a ForeignKey to `Alisting`, and `new_bid` IntegerField for the latest bid.

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Alisting(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    sta_bid = models.IntegerField()
    las_bid = models.ForeignKey(Bid, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Bid(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Alisting, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    new_bid = models.IntegerField()
```

How could I connect these 2 models so that when I create a listing I can create new bids to this listing from the other model. Because later in the project I'll have to allow users to modify bids from other user's listings.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this design:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Alisting(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    sta_bid = models.IntegerField()
   
    @property
    def last_bid(self):
       # You don' t need to update last_bid, since is obtained dynamically with this property
       if self.bid_set.objects.count() > 0:
          return self.bid_set.order('-creation_date')[0]
       return None

class Bid(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Alisting, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    new_bid = models.IntegerField()
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  # Stores the date when the bid was created
```

You can access the last bid with:

```py
listing = Alisting.objects.all()[0]
print(listing.last_bid)
```

You can access the bids of a listing with:

```py
listing = Alisting.objects.all()[0]
listings.bid_set.objects.all()
# Or to get only bids of a given user
listings.bid_set.objects.filter(user=User.objects.all()[0])
```

You can access bids of an user with:

```py
user = User.objects.all()[0]
user.bid_set.objects.all()
# Or to get only bids of an user with a given listing
user.bid_set.objects.filter(listing=Alisting.objects.all()[0])
```

You can access listings created by a given user with:

```py
user = User.objects.all()[0]
user.alisting_set.objects.all()
```